# Реализовать алгоритм шифрования данных на php

Tags: php, oracle

Есть функция написанная на Oracle для шифрования пароля

```
 Function Fc_Encrypt_Random_Number(In_Random_Number In Number,
              In_Password_Hash In Varchar2) Return Varchar2 Is
              Raw_Random_Number Raw(2000);
              Raw_Password_Hash Raw(2000);
              Result            Varchar2(2000);
  Begin
             Raw_Random_Number := Utl_I18n.String_To_Raw(In_Random_Number, 'AL32UTF8');
              Raw_Password_Hash := Utl_Raw.Cast_To_Raw(Convert(Upper(In_Password_Hash), 'AL32UTF8'));
            Result := Dbms_Crypto.Encrypt(Typ => Dbms_Crypto.Aes_Cbc_Pkcs5, Src =>   Raw_Random_Number, Key => Raw_Password_Hash, Iv => '00000000000000000000000000000000');
    Return(Result);
  End;
```

Возможно ли ее написать на php?

Comment: Точно возможно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как?

Comment: Разобраться как работает код и переписать его на PHP, вы не поверите...